# When I open a file using 'Open With...' in context menu, how can I open that application as administor?

Tags: windows-7, windows, context-menu

In Windows, when I open a file using 'Open With...' in context menu, how can I open that application (notepad) 'as administrator'?

My user account already has administrator right. And when I 'open with ...' in context menu, and when I save the file, I get permission declined.

I work around it by going to task bar, and right click notepad and 'run as administrator', open the same file, and save it. It works if I do that.

Answer (score 0):

Go into:

```
Drive:\Windows\System32\
```

Find Notepad.exe

Right click: create shortcut

Save the shortcut to your desktop

Then, go into shortcut properties, click advanced, run as admin. Now you can use this shortcut to run notepad as admin!

EDIT: The shortcut cant be added to open with, but I found this simple little app to add a Open with Notepad Admin to context menu:

```
[version]
signature="$CHICAGO$"

[NotepadAsAdminInstall]
CopyFiles = NotepadAsAdmin.Files.Inf
AddReg    = NotepadAsAdmin.AddReg

[DefaultInstall]
CopyFiles = NotepadAsAdmin.Files.Inf
AddReg    = NotepadAsAdmin.AddReg

[DefaultUnInstall]
DelFiles  = NotepadAsAdmin.Files.Inf
DelReg    = NotepadAsAdmin.DelReg

[SourceDisksNames]
55="Notepad as Admin","",1

[SourceDisksFiles]
NotepadAsAdmin.INF=55

[DestinationDirs]
NotepadAsAdmin.Files.Inf = 17

[NotepadAsAdmin.Files.Inf]
NotepadAsAdmin.INF

[NotepadAsAdmin.AddReg]
HKLM,%UDHERE%,DisplayName,,"%NotepadAsAdminName%"
HKLM,%UDHERE%,UninstallString,,"rundll32.exe syssetup.dll, SetupInfObjectInstallAction DefaultUninstall 132 %17%\NotepadAsAdmin.inf"
HKCR,*\Shell\runas,,,"%NotepadAsAdminAccel%"
HKCR,*\Shell\runas\command,,,"%11%\notepad.exe ""%1"""

[NotepadAsAdmin.DelReg]
HKLM,%UDHERE%
HKCR,Directory\Shell\runas
HKCR,Drive\Shell\runas

[Strings]
NotepadAsAdminName="Notepad as Admin PowerToy (Uninstall only)"
NotepadAsAdminAccel="Notepad as Admin"
UDHERE="Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\NotepadAsAdmin"
```

Now paste the code into notepad, save as notepadadmin.inf. Now, right click the file and click install. All done! This can be uninstalled though control panel.

Original link: http://www.wikihow.com/Add-an-%22Open-With-Notepad-As-Administrator%22-Shortcut-to-the-Context-Menu-in-Windows-7-and-Windows-Vista

Comment: you can also use a  shortcut to do the same thing without copying the executable